# How can I change a form submit action from displaying an alert popup to redirecting to a new page?

Tags: javascript, redirect, contact-form

I'm trying to troubleshoot something someone else created (never a fun prospect) and want to eliminate an alert popup and have the user redirected to another page after form submission ... I've searched the web and found a couple of possible alternatives, but I also don't want to blow up the page, as I'm not all that experienced in PHP troubleshooting ... this is, I'm guessing, a painfully simple 101-level question, but many thanks in advance ... here's the relevant code:

```
    jQuery("form#commentform input#submit").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var name = jQuery("form#commentform input#author").val();
        if(name=="") {
            alert("Name cannot be empty!");
            jQuery("form#commentform input#author").focus();
            return false;   
        }

        var email = jQuery("form#commentform input#email").val();
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
        var email_test= pattern.test(email);  

        if (email == "" || email_test == false) {
            alert('Valid email address is required!');
            jQuery("form#commentform input#email").focus();
            return false;
        }

        var phone = jQuery("form#commentform input#url").val();
        var comment = jQuery("form#commentform textarea#comment").val();

        jQuery.get('http://theenergyclub.com/wp-content/themes/EnergyClub/formPost.php', {type:'guestpass', name:name, email:email, phone:phone, comment:comment, rnDnum:Math.random()}, function(data) {
            alert('We have received your request. Thank you!');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace the last line

```
alert('We have received your request. Thank you!');
```

with

```
window.location = "http://example.com/"
```

Comment: If there's gonna be a redirect then wouldn't it be better to just use direct form submits?

Comment: Yes, it would be better, but I'm not sure, if Craig wants to go to submitted page or just to some other page. I also noticed some parameters not in the html form, like `rnDnum:Math.random()`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just change `alert('We have received your request. Thank you!');` to `window.location = '<URL>';` where `<URL>` is the URL you want to re-direct the user to.